# Loading word's .docm document

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop

I've tried to load a document with .docm extension with like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application  
             ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Document doc = ap.Documents.Open(docName);
```

The file won't open, I see in the task manager a process of winword

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't have an issue with file permissions or aren't specifying an invalid file as those things would result in a COM Exception.  You don't have a catch on Exception that is eating the exception, are you?

Comment: if i double click the file, it's open without any security questions

Comment: any solution on this?